# Badge is not set when getting message from server in IOS 13

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, ios13, react-native-firebase, firebase-notifications

I used react-native-firebase to show notification and set app badge in my app.

When server sends message with badge count, in most case, it works fine.
But sometimes, app badge is not updated even if server sends right message(set badge count in aps section).

It only happens on the IOS 13. Is it known issue in IOS 13?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem without react native. Did you find the reason?